# simplexml_load_string warnings

Tags: php, simplexml, libxml2

I am using `simplexml_load_string` function of php to convert xml string into object that can be used for futhur processing.

I code like this :

```
simplexml_load_string( $strXml, NULL, LIBXML_NOWARNING );
```

gives warning messages but executes it properly.

Where as if i code like this :

```
simplexml_load_string( $strXml, NULL, LIBXML_ERR_NONE );
```

failed to execute service.

I have already tried for `LIBXML_ERR_NONE`, `LIBXML_ERR_ERROR`.

Is there any way to get the object but without warning messages?

Comment: Isn't it better to start with a proper XML file instead of suppressing the errors?

Comment: I'm with @Dirk on this one: what are the warnings, and why do you want to suppress them?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
simplexml_load_string($strXml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_NOERROR);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress these errors by calling [libxml_use_internal_errors](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php).

```php
libxml_use_internal_errors (true);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($user_input);
if (!$xml) {
    $xml_errors = libxml_get_errors();
    foreach ($xml_errors as $err) {
        var_dump($err);
    }
    libxml_clear_errors();
}
```

You might also want to check out [libxml_get_errors](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) and [libxml_clear_errors](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-clear-errors.php)